# Check new messages on database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

First of all im sorry for my bad English. im from Sri Lanka and im bad in English. I'm trying to create a chat site. but i have a problem checking for m=new messages. i used jquery setInterval() and ajax to check messages.

```
function chat() {
    var fid = $('#send').data('id');
    $.ajax({ url: "php/control/chat.php", type: 'post', dataType: 'json', data: { fid: fid }, success: function (obj) {
            if(obj){
                browser.find('.chat-view .seen').hide();
                browser.find('.user-chat .chat-view').append(function () {
                    var msgs = '';
                    for( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                        msgs += '<div class="user u2 d-flex flex-row">' +
                                  '   <span class="msg">' +
                                  '   <span class="text">' + obj[i].msg + '</span>' +
                                  '       <span class="time">' + nowTime(obj[i].sent) + '</span>' +
                                  '   </span>' +
                                  '</div>';
                    }
                    return msgs;
                });
                browser.find('.chat-view').animate({scrollTop:browser.find('.chat-view')[0].scrollHeight});
            }
        }
    });
}

setInterval(function () {
    if(browser.find('div.chat-view').hasClass('chat-view') && browser.css('display') == 'block') {
        chat();
    }
}, 500);
```

i set to reply 0 from php when there is no new messages to reduce data usage. This works fine. but when there was no messages it still use 370 bytes for 1 reply and its about 45KB for a minute.

I checked facebook in chrome inspect and found out they are using a method to send a request to the server and wait for a new message or notification. server reply for that request only if there is something new. i tried using php sleep() function but i think it might cause a DoS attack on server. i cant check on WAMP because it only allow one request at one time. Please help me if someone know how to wait for a request without causing the server to stuck.

Comment: I think you are trying to make a real-time chat app. You want your server to send a response when an event occurs (new message) right? That can be achieved using the web socket and I don't that PHP is best for implementing a real-time web app. Even if you want to go ahead then you might want to do some research on Ratchet.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to make a real-time chat app. but i want it to be web based like facebook. and my knowledge is limited to php, html, css and javascript

Comment: It is not impossible to do it in PHP. Search for Ratchet on Google that might help you to implement real time chat